# Error using Qt during build: C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have Qt Creator with compiler Desktop **x86-windows-msvc2019-pe-64bit**, Qt Creator 4.11.1 ("based on Qt 5.14.1 MSVC2017, 32 bit), built Feb 5 2020, Boost library 1.72 and also Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2019.

During the building of my program in Qt I get this error:

**C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol**

Actually the solution is written on this page: https://studiofreya.com/2018/01/06/visual-studio-2017-with-cpp17-and-boost/#stdbyte-ambiguous-symbol-and-rpcndr.h
The problem is I am using Qt (not VS) and have no idea how turn this compiler behaviour off.

Would you know how to avoid this error?

The beginning of my project file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += charts

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

INCLUDEPATH += "c:/Qt/boost_1_72_0/"
```

Comment: Do you, perchance, have a line akin to `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code? If so, maybe look here: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

Comment: Yes, I have. I will try to rework all code and get back to you.

Comment: I deleted it from .h header files and it works now. Many thanks Adrian .-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Adrian advised -  [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) - I deleted

```
using namespace std;
```

from header files of my classes and used std:: prefix where needed and voila, the error is away.

Comment: Yep, corrected.